# Node Express serving old build of angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx

I have new build of angular on local express is serving the new build but on server it is showing two versions old build.
i replaced the old build with new one and then i had some changes in server side file not something related to serving of build.
i restarted the PM2 and ngnix server
instead of showing me new its showing me two version old build.
if its caching then it should serve the last version instead of 2nd last.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist/mdb-angular-free")));
app.use("/index", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist/mdb-angular-free")));
app.use("/policy", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist/mdb-angular-free")));
app.use("/pdfs", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "pdfs")));
app.use("/step1", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist/mdb-angular-free")));
```

Thats how routes are serving files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is local or server level cache?

1. Try testing with incognito mode of browser if that still fails to show you correct version that means your server has some kind of cache.
2. Other error could be the newly started app is running on new port number and old app is still running on old port number.

Comment: there is not caching.
if somehow there is some cache then it should the last release instead of 2nd last

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).